# Add Quotation Marks Within Specific Region of a String

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to format a string within my VBA code that will add quotation marks within a specific region of said string, in this case just the date, so another code block can either loop through the data or do a vlookup for a specific string that matches a keyword. I will give an example below.

Variable string: appointmentArrivalTime:"2018-08-26 01:00:00.000000"
Keyword/string: "2018-08-24 01:00:00.000000"

The date will constantly change based on the current date, so the above is just an example.

Example code:

```
Dim Main As Worksheet
    Set Main = Worksheets("Main")
Dim ISA_List As Worksheet
    Set ISA_List = Worksheets("ISA_List")
Dim ISA_Results As Worksheet
    Set ISA_Results = Worksheets("ISA_Results")
Dim Oculus_Raw As Worksheet
    Set Oculus_Raw = Worksheets("Oculus_Raw")
Dim ContainWord As String
Dim CWDate As String

CWDate = Worksheets("Main").Range("Date")

ContainWord = "appointmentArrivalTime:" & Format(CWDate, "YYYY-MM-DD")
```

What I need is for VBA/Excel to look at a cell named "Date" which contains the current date, format the string so it contains "appointmentArrivalTime" and the current date, which in this case is "CWDate" and then add quotation marks as follows.

appointmentArrivalTime:"2018-08-24"

Currently my code only gives me the following:

"appointmentArrivalTime:2018-08-24"

Hopefully what I am asking makes sense. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
MsgBox "appointmentArrivalTime:" & Chr(34) & Format(CDate(CWDate), "YYYY-MM-DD") & Chr(34)
```

My message box output:

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: I may have been slightly ambiguous in my post and if I was, I apologize, but I did not need a message box; I needed a variable string. However, minus the message box, the rest of it works if I set it to another variable. So thank you!

Comment: @JosephBay I'm aware you don't need a message box; I tested it using a message box because it's the quickest way - in my opinion - to screw around with strings and get an immediate answer.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes. Apologies if I offended. I did not intend to.

Comment: You didn't; it's near-impossible to offend me.